# Algorithm for generating normally distributed random values in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, statistics, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a Uniform Distribution to a Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution)

Hello.

I'd like to know of any algorithm implemented in C which can take a random value between 0 and 1, the mean and standard deviation and then return a normally distributed result.

I have too little brainpower to figure this out for myself right now.

I can't find anything useful on the internet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's already been the suggestion for Box Muller, but a computationally simpler approach is simply to take advantage of the [central-limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central-limit_theorem); add enough independent random variables together, and the result will approximate a normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will this be efficient enough since many random numbers are needed? Apparently 32 are needed to get a good enough representation.

Comment: @Matthew Mitchell: It's not possible to answer that answer definitively, without knowing your platform or your accuracy requirements.  Your best bet may be to implement both methods and profile.  All I can say is that the Box-Muller transform requires evaluations of log, cos, and sqrt, which may well be expensive.

Comment: It's only for AI and doesn't have to be 100% accurate. Since the function will only be needed seldom I think the speed isn't important anyway.

Comment: I can't find a *working* Box Muller C function anywhere. I'm giving up on that front. I will try and test the central-limit algorithm. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Matthew Mitchell: That's a good response!  There are far too many people that obsess over optimising the speed/performance of an algorithm without stopping to check whether it's actually necessary to do so.

Comment: The normal distribution representation is supposed to represent a standard normal distribution, right? That's important since I need to be able to set the mean and standard deviation correctly.

Comment: I believe all you need to do is sum your *N* uniform variables (in [0,1]), sutract 0.5'N', and divide by sqrt('N') to get a standard normal distribution.

Comment: All of the sudden I think I remember doing this for A-level mathematics. That was a year ago. I should remember these things a little better. XD

Comment: Ah yes, the standard deviation of the means is the standard deviation of the distribution divided by the square root of the sample size. For random numbers between 0 and 1 the standard deviation is 0.316227766 I hope.

Comment: Well with a little fiddling I got something which works reasonably. For my purposes at least. http://utilitybase.com/paste/wjw I was unable to find a very good histogram utility to test it though.

Comment: +1 (and a lot more if I could give it!) for central limit theorem. I was about to give this answer before I scrolled down and saw you'd already written it.

Answer (score 10):

[Box-Muller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) is the transform you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need a C implementation or readable pseudocode, not an incomprehensible wikipedia page.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude there, I just need something I can comprehend and use straight away. I am looking for a decent website for that algorithm however, so thank you for your suggestion.