# drawing random number from a standard normal distribution using the standard rand() functions

Tags: math, variables, random, statistics, numbers

So most programming languages contain a rand() functionality whereby you can generate a random number between 0 to 1....

My question is, is there a way to manipulate this standard rand() functionality such that you are able to instead draw a random number from normal distribution with a mean and standard deviation?

Notice that I'm not asking whether or not a language has a normal distribution functionality built in, I'm asking if you can "simulate" drawing a normal distribution random variable using a rand() function...

Comment: Does this help: [converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way that works (from [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=w47cyQLVQowC&lpg=PA368&ots=PLY_fm-_az&dq=%22ratio%20of%20uniforms%22%20normal%20distribution&hl=fr&pg=PA369#v=onepage&q=%22ratio%20of%20uniforms%22%20normal%20distribution&f=false)):

```
    static Random r = new Random();
    static double Normal(double mu, double sig)
    {
        double u, v, x, y, q;
        do
        {
            u = r.NextDouble();
            v = 1.7156 * (r.NextDouble() - 0.5);
            x = u - 0.449871;
            y = Math.Abs(v) + 0.386595;
            q = Math.Sqrt(x) + y * (0.19600 * y - 0.25472 * x);
        } while (q > 0.27597 && (q > 0.27846 || Math.Sqrt(v) > -4.0 * Math.Log(u) * Math.Sqrt(u)));
        return mu + sig * v / u;
    }
```