# Random numbers in the shape of a bell curve

Tags: algorithm, random

I need to manipulate random to produce a statistical average with the shape of a bell curve, here is my attempt:

```
Function slopedrand(max As Single, bias As Single) As Integer
    Dim count As Single = 0
    While count < bias
        max = rand.NextDouble() * max
        count += rand.NextDouble()
    End While
    Return rand.NextDouble() * max
End Function

Function bulgedrand(min As Single, max As Single, bulge As Single, bias As Single)
    Dim negative = bulge - min
    Dim positive = max - bulge

    Dim nr = min + slopedrand(negative, bias)
    Dim pr = max - slopedrand(positive, bias)

    Return rand.NextDouble() * (pr - nr) + nr
End Function
```

however, given that I suck at math, all it produces is stuff like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YTba.png

which is more like a bulge...

Since it feels like my skull is boiling, maybe somebody here has figured out how to accomplish what I need and will spare me from further attempts of thinking?

(the example is given in vb.net since it was quick to prototype on but any language is welcome)

Comment: What language is this regarding? It looks like vb.net at a guess.

Comment: Won't `rand() + rand()` basically give you something approaching a Bell curve?

Comment: When you say "Bell curve", do you mean a normal (Gaussian) distribution? If so then I can make my answer more specific.

Comment: thats visual basic of some form.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's vb.net, vb6 and vba do not allow you to declare and define in the same "statement". But the OP could confirm...

Comment: how about read the post? specifically the last line :)

Comment: Please do not delete questions just because you think you have understood them (and “I switched to `double`” is barely an explanation). Talking about your recently deleted question, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "established" way of doing this is to draw a uniformly distributed random number in the range [0, 1), then apply the *quantile* function of the Bell curve distribution. This then gives you a random number that has the same distribution as the Bell curve.

Answer (score 0):

A bell curve can be approximated by a normal distribution, so I guess you can use random values inside the formula for a normal distribution and get the effect you need, such as in this answer:

[drawing random number from a standard normal distribution using the standard rand() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739851/drawing-random-number-from-a-standard-normal-distribution-using-the-standard-ran)

Maybe it can help you?