# Where do the magic numbers in this normal RNG come from?

Tags: random, normal-distribution, magic-numbers

A popular method to generate normally distributed numbers comes from the ratio of uniform deviates technique derived by Kinderman and Monahan and improved by Leva. [The method is compact and requires little memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739851/drawing-random-number-from-a-standard-normal-distribution-using-the-standard-ran):

```
static Random r = new Random();
static double Normal(double mu, double sig)
{
    double u, v, x, y, q;
    do
    {
        u = r.NextDouble();
        v = 1.7156 * (r.NextDouble() - 0.5);
        x = u - 0.449871;
        y = Math.Abs(v) + 0.386595;
        q = Math.Sqrt(x) + y * (0.19600 * y - 0.25472 * x);
    } while (q > 0.27597 && (q > 0.27846 || Math.Sqrt(v) > -4.0 * Math.Log(u) * Math.Sqrt(u)));
    return mu + sig * v / u;
}
```

The [Leva paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/85ee/3008e18f41a76b975a780820c30e1b8ae29a.pdf) describes the equations and solutions, but it isn't clear to me how the values were determined:

```
acceptance region: v^2 < -4*u^2*ln(u)

inner boundary: v = ± u*sqrt(5 - 5.136102*u)
outer boundary: v = ± u*sqrt(1.4 + 1.03696/u)

quadratic form: Q(u,v) = (u-s)^2 - b*(u-s)*(v-t) + a*(v-t)^2

s  = 0.449871
t  = -0.386595
r1 = 0.27597

a  = 0.19600
b  = 0.25472
r2 = 0.27846
```

Where do the magic numbers for `v, s, t, r1, a, b, r2` come from?

Comment: This question seems better suited to math.stackexchange.com (or perhaps stats.stackexchange.com). But from the paper, "These ellipses are optimal in that they are an equal ripple quadratic fit to the boundary of A." It looks as though your next step would be to find out more about equal-ripple error curves.