# How to calculate in PHP, Normal Distribution that exactly matches Excel Result using NORMDIST(x, mean, standard_dev, accumulative)

Tags: php, normal-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a Uniform Distribution to a Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution)

I need to calculate in PHP, Normal Distribution that matches results using Excel Normal Distribution Function `NORMDIST(x, mean, standard_dev, accumulative)`

I tried few methods but couldn't get correct results which is 0.513 according to the Excel formula of `NORMDIST(x, mean, standard_dev, accumulative)` with following input values:

```
Z=65, mean=64.43, standard_dev=18.76, accumulative=1
```

Result should be `0.513`

Any help please ?