# Random Number function of VB6 distribution

Tags: vb6

I am used on other programming languages which let you set the distribution you want to use on a random number generator. I tried to find in docs the same for VB6, but I cannot even tell which distribution uses. (I guess it is the uniform)

Here is the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx)

And it easy to use as: `Public Shared Function Rnd[(Number)] As Single`

I still want to generate a random number between 0 and 1, but instead of uniform (or what the default Rnd uses), I want the normal distribution. Is there any way to do this in VB6 or you need a custom function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution

Comment: @Rob This means that there isn't a built function in vb6. Right?

Comment: correct, no built in one (which languages do?)

Comment: Python, but not built in. Mostly on libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in. You need a custom function - see [this question for algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution).