# How do I randomly sample a normal distribution with a given mean and standard error in C++?

Tags: c++

How to get a random number for given mean and standard error in C++? Are there any built-in functions that can be used straightway?

I am aware of some examples, which using mean and standard deviation to get a random number. However, I do not know the number of replications and only have the mean and standard error, so I would not be able to calculate the standard deviation. Any thoughts?

I appreciate your time and help. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to randomly sample a normal distribution?

Comment: [<random>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) has several distributions, normal distribution seems the one you want.

Comment: Hi alcedine,

Thanks for your reply. Yes, I want to randomly sample a normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`std::normal_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution) in `<random>` in C++11, as well as other distributions. You'll need to separately create a generator object and a distribution object; the cppreference.com page I linked has a good example of usage.

Prior to C++11, nothing like that exists in the standard library, though you might want to use Boost.

Comment: Thanks, alcedine! Currently, I would not be able to get standard deviation. I only have data like 20.2 (mean) ± 1.2 (standard error). I would like to have a random number within this range. :-)

Comment: You would then initialize the distribution object accordingly: `std::normal_distribution<> d(20.2, 1.2);`.

Comment: According to the web page,  
      std::normal_distribution<> d(x,y);
x is the mean. y is the standard deviation, and not the standard error.

Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is meant to be.

Comment: The standard error of the mean (SE of the mean) estimates the variability between sample means that you would obtain if you took multiple samples from the same population. The standard error of the mean estimates the variability between samples whereas the standard deviation measures the variability within a single sample (http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/basic-statistics-and-graphs/hypothesis-tests/tests-of-means/what-is-the-standard-error-of-the-mean/).

Comment: That webpage is for the "standard error *of the mean*", while earlier you just said "standard error", which makes me think maybe it's just that your task is using the term "standard error" to refer to the standard deviation (which I initially assumed you were doing).

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I actually mean the "standard error of the mean".

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, as this parameter wasn't familiar to me. Well, in that case, you can sample the distribution of the means, but to sample the distribution of the actual population's values you'd need to know the standard deviation, which you can't get unless you know the sample size, unfortunately.

Comment: standard error of the mean = standard deviation/√n (n is the size, number of observations, of the sample)

Comment: Thanks for your help, alcedine! :-)

Answer (score 0):

A general answer would be to get a **uniform** random number on a unit [0,1] and then apply a transformation to map that value to the distribution you need.
For a normal distribution, check this post out. [Converting a Uniform Distribution to a Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution)