# Matlab : Gaussian density cloud

Tags: matlab

I look for develop by my own a cloud of points with a density which is a Gaussian.

I find a first solution, but I would like to make it by my own.

```
X = [mvnrnd([x_centroid,y_centroid],[diameter 0; 0 diameter],number_points)]
```

Have you an idea ?

Comment: mmm... So you have a fucntion and you want to make your own function that does the same thing? What is the purpose? Wat have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get gaussian random values from:

```
x = meanval + sigma*randn(N, 1);
```

If you get several vectors like x, it would be a gaussian cloud.

Or you can convert it from even distribution: [Converting a Uniform Distribution to a Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution)

Comment: How can I get a 2D gaussian random value ? I would get a vector X=[x,y] with a hist3 that is gaussian