# Converting a Uniform Distribution to a Fat-tailed Distribution

Tags: algorithm, random, statistics, language-agnostic, distribution

[This previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution) regards converting a Uniform distribution to a Normal distribution.

For Monte-Carlo simulations, I have a need not only for Normal (Gaussian), but for some computationally efficient ways to generate large numbers of samples from ["fat-tailed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-tailed_distribution) or [heavy-tailed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution) distributions, using a given (64-bit or double) uniform RNG as input.  Examples of these distributions include: Log-normal, Pareto, Student-T, and Cauchy.

Use of inverse CDFs is acceptable given computationally efficient means of computing the inverse CDF as needed.

The tag is for a language-independant algorithms, but the implementations needed are for basic procedural programming languages (C, Basic, procedural Swift, Python, et.al.)

Comment: [How to generate a Cauchy random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484395/how-to-generate-a-cauchy-random-variable)

Comment: This is the subject of several books, and is therefore, I believe, the classic case of "too broad". Here is one of the books, by Christian Walck of Stockholm University [Handbook On Statistical Distributions for Experimentalists](http://staff.fysik.su.se/~walck/suf9601.pdf).

Comment: I agree with @rici.  [Here](http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/) and [here](http://www.eirene.de/Devroye.pdf) are links to a (quite large) text written by Luc Devroye back in 1986.  It contains a multiplicity of algorithms to generate from a huge variety of distributions, take your pick.

Comment: Excellent sources.  However I note that for the 4 distributions I asked about, these texts describe reasonable algorithms that would easily fit in a stackoverflow answer box.

Comment: @hotpaw2: if you had asked about one distribution, fine. But you said, "Examples include... et al", which requires a much more extensive response.

Comment: @pjs: thanks. I was looking for those links but I got distracted.

Answer (score 1):

A Cauchy random number can be expressed as:

```
scale * tan(pi * (RNDU01OneExc()-0.5)) + mu
```

Where `RNDU01OneExc()` is a random number in [0, 1), and `mu` and `scale` are the offset and scale, respectively.

A logarithmic normal random number can be expressed as `exp(Normal(mu, sigma))`, where `Normal(mu, sigma)` is a normally distributed random number with mean `mu` and standard deviation `sigma`.

These and other kinds of distributions are mentioned in [my article](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Specific_Non_Uniform_Distributions) on random number generation and sampling.