# Sample in normal distribution from random numbers

Tags: math, gaussian, normal-distribution

I have a function `random(start, end)` that can return a random number from the start to end.

How can I sample a new number in normal distribution(given mean and variance) from the random numbers?

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Stackoverflow: Converting a uniform distribution to a normal distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution) [Mathoverflow: How do I convert a uniform value in [0,1) to a standard normal gaussian distribution?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28557/how-do-i-convert-a-uniform-value-in-0-1-to-a-standard-normal-gaussian-distri) [Stats.stackexchange: generating rando](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236149/generating-random-numbers-from-normal-distribution-via-inverse-uniform-distribut)

Comment: @Stef Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a Uniform Distribution to a Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution)