# How can I generate random numbers which fall in a normal distribution pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

I will need to initialize an 'n' number of classes that will have a random value attached to them from 1 to 100.

I know how to create a random value between 1 and 100 but how can I make all the values to fall in a the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) pattern?

```
+ (int)randomIntBetweenMinimum:(int)minimum maximum:(int)maximum {
    
    return (int)(minimum + arc4random_uniform(maximum - minimum + 1.0f));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a Uniform Distribution to a Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution)

Comment: Are you sure you want to base your results on a normal?  1) The support for a normal is infinite, so you'd actually have to generate a truncated normal.  2) If you use a small standard deviation then you'll almost never get low values or high ones;  if you use a large standard deviation you'll likely have to throw away a lot of values that are out of range.  Would you consider other distributions which have bounded integer support, such as [binomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) or discrete [triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution)?

Answer (score 1):

There are some APIs to generate a Gaussian Distribution.

I believe that you can do the following to get what you're looking for:

```
GKRandomSource *random = [[GKRandomSource alloc] init];
GKRandomDistribution *distribution;
distribution = [[GKGaussianDistribution alloc]
              initWithRandomSource:random lowestValue:1 highestValue:100];

int randomVal = [distribution nextInt];
```