# How to generate random normal distribution without numpy? (Google interview)

Tags: python, statistics

So I have a data science interview at Google, and I'm trying to prepare. One of the questions I see   a lot (on Glassdoor) from people who have interviewed there before has been: "Write code to generate random normal distribution." While this is easy to do using numpy, I know sometimes Google asks the candidate to code without using any packages or libraries, so basically from scratch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a Uniform Distribution to a Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution)

Comment: You must check the normal distribution theory. Because you need calculated some variables, with the froms of theory.

Comment: random.gauss() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) a normalised summation of independent random variables will approach a normal distribution. The simplest demonstration of this is adding two dice together.

So maybe something like:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pseudo_norm():
    """Generate a value between 1-100 in a normal distribution"""
    count = 10
    values =  sum([random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(count)])
    return round(values/count)
    
dist = [pseudo_norm() for x in range(10_000)]
n_bins = 100
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Pseudo-normal')
hist = ax.hist(dist, bins=n_bins)
plt.show()
```

Which generates something like:
[image: Pseudo-normal generated sample]

Answer (score 2):

(*Probably a bit late to the party but I had the same question and found a different solution which I personally prefer.*)

You can use the [Box-Muller Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) to generate two independent random real numbers `z_0` and `z_1` that follow a standard normal distribution (zero mean and unit variance) using two uniformly distributed numbers `u_1` and `u_2` .

#### Example

If you want to generate N random numbers that follow a normal distribution just like `np.random.randn(n)` does you can do something like the following:

```
import math
import random

rands = []
for i in range(N):
    u1 = random.uniform(0, 1)
    u2 = random.uniform(0, 1)
    
    z0 = math.sqrt(-2 * math.log(u1)) * math.cos(2 * math.pi * u2)
    rands.append(z0)
    # z1 can be discarded (or cached for a more efficient approach)
    # z1 = math.sqrt(-2 * math.log(u1)) * math.sin(2 * math.pi * u2)
```

If you plot a histogram of `rands` you'll verify the numbers are indeed normally distributed. The following is the distribution of 100000 random numbers with 100 bins:
[image]